# How to merge a field when there is a duplicate in 2 columns

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like this:

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
---|------|------|----- 
1  | ABC  | 123  | Dogs 
2  | ABC  | 123  | Cats
```

How can I compare the values in both Col1 and Col2 and then merge the Col3 values to get this:

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
---|------|------|----- 
1  | ABC  | 123  | Dogs, Cats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Col1, a.Col2, GROUP_CONCAT(a.COl3) as Col3
FROM table a
GROUP BY a.Col1, a.Col2
```

Comment: I think it needs "separator" : `GROUP_CONCAT(a.COl3 SEPARATOR ', ') as Col3`

Comment: @byakugie - indeed, if the space after the comma is critical. Otherwise the default separator is a comma, which will give `Dogs,Cats`